# Scrapy will not scrawl(Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I'm trying to get course name out of a university website, but Scrapy won't crawl the data. I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**Item.py:**
[image]

**Course_spider.py**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modify your xpath and the problem will be solved:

① replace """ with " or ' in your xpath.

② if the problem still exists, use a different way to write the xpath. Try using scrapy shell and view the response to see if your spider 'sees' the page the same way you do.

Here is the doc of [scrapy shell](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) in case you needed.